# How to pass viewBag data into Javascript and display in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, razor, viewdata

I am always leery of asking dumb questions here but I need to move on and create a few more active pages but this is a lingering issue in my way ...The chtml in razor contains a switch ,,, in one of the cases there's three if statements.. **THIS IS JUST ONE OF THEM**  depending on the if statements a different string in viewdata is to be fed into a div and the div class "hidden" is removed and the supplied text displayed....
I have over the past few hours regained my briefly lost ability to remove that hidden class (I hate css) but I have never been able to update the content of the div.
PLEASE Advise  Thank you !!

```
<div id="divUnUsableEvent" class="hidden">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div id="systemExceptionLbl" style="font-size: 2em; color: red;" 
                class="text-danger:focus">
               Please contact IS support
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>

    //alphascores Not present  AND   BetaSCores  Not Present Ready for xxxxx     //alphascores Not present  AND   BetaSCores  Not Present Ready for xxxxx Scoring
if (!Convert.ToBoolean(@ViewData["alphaPresent"]) 
   && !Convert.ToBoolean(@ViewData["betaPresent"]))
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#UnUseableEvent').addClass("hidden");
            var txtMsg = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["beforeAlpha"]));
            $('#divUnUsableEvent').removeClass("hidden");
            $('#systemExceptionLbl').removeClass("hidden");
            $('#systemExceptionLbl').innerText  = txtMsg;
        });
    </script>

    <a id="XXXReScoreEvent" 
        href="@Url.Action("Readyforxxxxxx", "Exception", new { Id = (int)@ViewData["Id"] })"
        class="btn btn-primary btn-default btn-too-large pull-left margin" 
        aria-label="XXXReScoreEvent">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>  Ready for xxxxxx Scoring
    </a>
}
break;
```

I know its hitting the javascript, as that html element (a button) named '#UnUseableEvent' is correctly being hidden in this case.   I of course would want the javascript out of this html page and just have function calls in the razor  but baby steps

Specifically regarding the ('#systemExceptionLbl').innerText  = txtMsg;  I have tried

.text
   .value
   .innerHTML

all to no avail. I can see the correctly formatted Json.Encoded text reach the variable txtMsg,  but again I cant get it into the div ..

I am having success now with displaying the div (remove class hidden) I was attempting to affect the wrong div name and the line removing the hidden class from the element $('#systemExceptionLbl') is not needed.

I even tried to skip the JQuery reference and go old school document.getElementById('systemExceptionLbl').innerHTML = txtMsg;

Answer (score 1):

Ever tried :

```
$('#systemExceptionLbl').text( txtMsg );
```

or

```
$('#systemExceptionLbl').html( txtMsg );
```

as `innerText` is not a jquery function. Instead use `.html()` or `.text()` to insert data into it

Comment: Yes this was the trick ::     $('#systemExceptionLbl').html(txtMsg);

Comment: Thanks  reasoning behinnd this is BECAUSE Its JQuery thats trying to fill the DOM element and adding text in JQuery versus javascript uses the displayed syntax         $('#systemExceptionLbl').html( txtMsg );          or $('#systemExceptionLbl').text( txtMsg );         Hey when you've been doing desktop app & windows services most of your life those little web things seem like they were built to trip you up...